using CSS-Loader, Style-Loader with ngtools is generating TypeError: at ShadowCss.shimCssText (compiler.mjs)
`I am creating Angular V-18 project without CLI and but i cannot find the solution for this one
my package.json
my tsconfig.json
webpack.config.mjs
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url); const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
export default {
  entry: './src/main.ts',
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.mjs'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
            use: {
           loader: '@ngtools/webpack',
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.[cm]?js$/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                compact: false,
                plugins: [linkerPlugin],
                compact: false,
                cacheDirectory: true,
              }
            },
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        // css-loader converts css in js and then style-loader use that js so their positioning is very imp.
        use: [
          'style-loader', // inject that commonjs into DOM.
          {
            loader:'css-loader',
            options: {
              import: true,
            },
          }, // Turns CSS into commonjs.
        ],
      }
      // Add other rules as necessary
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    }),
    new AngularWebpackPlugin({
        tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
        entryModule: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/app.module#AppModule'),
        jitMode: true,  // JIT mode disabled for AOT
        directTemplateLoading: true  // Load templates directly from filesystem
    })
  ],
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    port: 4200,
    open: true
  }
}**`

`
ngtools with CSS-loader and Style-Loader is giving error on console,
error
I find a solution to use raw-loader in html and css but i need to know why i can't use CSS-loader and Style-loader also tell me which settings i can use to better my project.`

Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.
